# dotnet pack - error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v3.5 were not found

Tags: .net, nuget

I have a legacy project that is targeting .Net 3.5, i.e. `<TargetFramework>net35</TargetFramework>`, this project was building fine on my build server even after upgrading the csproj to SDK style.

I now want to package it as NuGet package so I have added this command to my build script:

```
dotnet pack MyProject.csproj -p:PackageVersion=1.2.3-build.4 --no-build --output .\nupkgs --configuration=Release
```

However this command is now failing my build with:
`error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v3.5 were not found`

Note that the MSBuild task preceding it works absolutely fine, it's just the `dotnet pack` that fails, I so I find it hard to believe it's an issue with missing .Net 3.5 SDK, nerveless I have double checked and the 3.5 development tools are present on the build agent, I can also see `C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\v3.5` folder present on the same machine.

I have tried adding a package reference to [Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETFramework.ReferenceAssemblies/1.0.0) but to no avail.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since anything < 4 is a bit.. „special“ in terms of how some parts of the build work (parts of msbuild then run on the 2.0 CLR), I suggest not using the `dotnet` CLI here but the Visual Studio installation‘s `msbuild.exe` (NOT the msbuild.exe from the global .NET Framework directory in windows):

```
msbuild -t:Pack —p:NoBuild=True -p:Configuration=Release -p:PackageOutputPath=.\nupkgs ...
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. In my case I needed to run it from an existing msbuild script so I used the <MSBuild> task.